# Perform segue when timer is finished

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to perform segue right after the timer reach 0. My code as below for the timer in the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if timerRunning == false {
            timerCounter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Counting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerRunning = true
        }

        if counter == 0 {
            timerRunning = false
        }
```

and this is the function counter:

```
func Counting() {

    counter -= 1
    timer.text = "\(counter)"
    if counter == 0 {
        timerCounter.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "resultView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You need to perform that segue operation on the main / UI thread I think.

Comment: when I run this code the app crash when timer reaches 0

Comment: Check to make sure you have given your segue the identifier `"resultView"`.

Comment: nothing wrong with the segue identifier

Comment: Are you running this in the simulator? What error is in the console log?

Comment: No in my phone, I got this error when I tried the below answer : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to perform the segue on the main thread. Use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "resultView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I put this line inside if counter == 0 and it shows me this error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the segue identifier is correct for both the performSegue call and in storyboards or xib, then perhaps self is somehow being deallocated before it should?

try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{

    [weak self] in

    self?.performSegue(WithIdentifier:"resultView", sender: self)

}
```

Or try optional chaining self before running the performSegue just to be sure.